# Zip files with whitespaces in name/folder

Tags: bash, whitespace, zip

Ok, so here I am, after spending hours in a stupid problem.
I need to make a bash script that among other things, zips the content of a folder.
Ok, no big deal, zip filename.zip files would do the trick. The problem is that the person creating the folders are putting some whitespaces in the name of the folder. I would use the "\" to escape the spaces in the folder easily if  I was not on a script, with the directory in a var.
The make it easier to understand, here's the script and the folder structure:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /dados/Pedagogico/RaquelRejane/teste -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/feito" ';' -print | while read dir
do
  mkdir "$dir/modificado"
  mogrify -path "$dir/modificado" -resize 800x600 "$dir/*.JPG"
  mogrify -path $dir"/modificado" -resize 800x600 $dir"/*.jpg"
  mogrify -path $dir"/modificado" -resize 800x600 $dir"/*.PNG"
  mogrify -path $dir"/modificado" -resize 800x600 $dir"/*.png"
  zip "$dir/modificado/modificado.zip" "$dir/modificado/*"
  touch "$dir/feito"
done
```

It does what it is intended to do, search folders that don't have the file feito in it, resizes some images into modificado directory inside it's original folder.
After that it should zip the resized images. That doesn't work. I can't zip the folder, I need to zip just the files. The directory is like this:

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 Sep  2 17:41 .
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root  4096 Sep  2 10:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 12288 Sep  2 16:26 Laguna - dia 27.8.14 - 4??s anos A ,B e F
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Sep  2 16:12 Laguna -dia 20.8.14 -4??s anos E,G e H
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Sep  2 16:17 Passeio ao Parque do Meio Ambiente - 2??s anos G e H - 14 e 15.8
```

What am I doing wrong? Any tips?

Comment: 1. Are you trying to include the ZIP archive in itself? -- modificado.zip is inside the subdirectory modificado/ 2. Remove the wildcard in the second argument and use the -r option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is the quoted wildcard because zip is trying to include ONLY a file named "/dados/Pedagogico/RaquelRejane/teste/abc/modificado/*" (for example) in the ZIP archive. Try instead

```
zip -r "$dir/modificado/modificado.zip" "$dir/modificado"
```

or

```
zip "$dir/modificado/modificado.zip" "$dir"/modificado/*
```

To prevent include the ZIP archive itself I would place the ZIP archive in other directory or exclude the ZIP archive by means of the -x option:

```
zip "$dir/modificado/modificado.zip" "$dir"/modificado/* -x "$dir"/modificado/modificado.zip
```

Comment: Much better. Or even `zip "$dir/modificado/modificado.zip" "$dir"/modificado/*.ext`

Comment: Perfect! I knew the quotes were the problem! It worked like a charm!